# What is a suitable DB structure of my problem?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

There will be many different pages with products.

The data of products are got from the database(id, name, description...) If a user likes a product, he will be able to click on a button named like "add this" and then the button will be changed to "added".

A user has the option to add several products on his "wish list". A product that he selected earlier will be presented like "added".

As a beginner, I know that there must be a way to have the `user_id` with the `product_id` in a row when that product was added.

As for now I have the `products` table. I guess I have to create another table that will save the `user_id` with the `product_id`?

Thank you for your ideas, hoping that I will clear up my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You need a table which relates users to the products they have selected:

```
CREATE TABLE selected_products
(
   choice_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id INT NOT NULL,
   product_id INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Retrieve user choices this way:

```
SELECT products.product_id, products.description 
FROM products JOIN selected_products ON products.product_id = selected_products.product_id
WHERE user_id = '$someuserid';
```

When a user wishes to remove the product from his selections, you only need to delete a row:

```
DELETE FROM selected_products WHERE user_id = '$someuserid' AND product_id = '$product_id';
```

Your `wishlist` table functions exactly the same way as your `selected_products` table. Same structure, same relationships.  You might also consider adding another column to indicate the timestamp when the product was added:

```
date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. It is for sure that it will help me. I will come back to you for any questions soon.

Comment: Does my DB have to be InnoDB or MyISAM

Comment: @JPampos Great question. Only InnoDB will enforce the foreign key relationships properly if you ever use things like `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  Use InnoDB, and that is the default in newer MySQL releases. I added it above.

Comment: @JPampos There aren't many reasons to use MyISAM anymore, except if you require full text searching on a column.

Comment: Because of the "strange" form of my application, an added product will be permanent, and will not be able to remove it. So, any delete operations will be made through phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

User Table - UserID (+ other user information)

Product Table - ProdID (+ other product information)

UserFavs Table - UserID, ProdID (+ other "faving" info eg date, refer link...)

---

I expect there will be others too -

UserWishList Table - UserID, ProdID (+ other wish info)

UserOwned Table - UserID, ProdID (+ other owned info)

---

This makes it clear you could have one table that relates users to products and describes that relationship, for example

UserProduct Table - UserID, ProdID, Relationship (one of owned, wished, favorite), (+ other relationship info)

Doing it with one table is a design choice which should be based on how your system is used.  If your system is about the relationship then one table will make sense.  If your system is about the user and the "lists" are seperate then seperate tables will make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

Create a table called user_products
add (at least) these columns:
id (primary key)
user_id (foreign key to your users table)
product_id (foreign key to the products table)

Insert a row to this table every time a product is liked.

Comment: I think it is a really simple nice way. Will this be faster instead of having different tables and Join `them` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your quetsion?
You already have the users table and the products table. Joining them won't help you in this case as you need to save each user' selection. Therefore you would need this third table to keep the relations between the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. products

```
id | name | description | ...
```

#### 2. users

```
id | name | email | ...
```

#### 3. wishlists

```
id | name | ...
```

#### 4. users_wishlists

```
user_id | wishlist_id | product_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a reference table for that.

Make sure you use InnoDB for your tables, so you can use real Foreign Keys

The reference table will mostly contain KEYS of referred tables and maybe some relevant meta data.
Easy example:

```
CREATE  TABLE `stackoverflow`.`users` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL , 
`cdate` DATETIME NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE `stackoverflow`.`products` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`price` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now the reference table with real FKs:

```
CREATE  TABLE `stackoverflow`.`user_likes_product` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
`id_product` INT NOT NULL ,
`time` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
INDEX `fk_user` (`id_user` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_product` (`id_product` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_user`
FOREIGN KEY (`id_user` )
REFERENCES `stackoverflow`.`users` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_product`
FOREIGN KEY (`id_product` )
REFERENCES `stackoverflow`.`products` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Another advice for starting to work with mysql (if you are on Windows):
Download and use [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.de/products/workbench/).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**User**

```
id | ...
```

**Wishlist**

```
id | user_id | ...
```

**Wishlist_Product**

```
wishlist_id | product_id | ...
```

**Product**

```
id | ...
```

This is basically what you've in online shops like Amazon. A `User` can own multiple `Wishlists`. A `Wishlist` can contain many `Products` and each `Product` can be on many `Wishlists`.

---

If you want to have only one `Wishlist` per `User` then you can go even simpler:
[image]

**User**

```
id | ...
```

**wishes**

```
user_id | product_id | ...
```

**Product**

```
id | ...
```